# How to import an excel query into an excel file automatically?

Tags: excel

I am having to manually import certain excel files into my excel workbook everyday. Is there a way wherein I can put in a formula and based on that formula my query will get automatically imported into the workbook from the specified folder?
I have multiple files in my folder and i do not need to import all off them. So, the New Query-from folder option doesn't work for me.

Folder name: Holding Statement
Files in that Folder: xxx which is a csv file, xx which is a pdf file, aa, aa1, aa2 which are excel files.
In my workbook, i need to import aa in sheet 1, aa1 in sheet 2 and aa2 in sheet 3.
Now suppose tomorrow there is a new file, aa3, i want that to be automatically imported to sheet 4.
Is this possible?

I have tried Data-New Query-From other sources-Blank query-Formula already. doesn't work for me

Comment: Why do you need to import those into new worksheets? Do they contain different data (structure-wise)? If so indeed there is no way to do this with PowerQuery. There must be a common denominator.

Comment: I need to upload these data to National Stock Exchange. Since this is to be done date wise, and everyday, I need them in different sheet.